# Read input fscanf with delimiter "_"

Tags: c

How can I scan the following in a txt file?

```
number_name_name1_number2
```

For example:

```
12_whoever_alternative with spaces_31
```

I've tried:

```
fscanf(f, "%d %[^_]_ %s %[^_]_ %s %[^_]_ %d", &number, name, name1, &number2)
```

Comment: You're trying to read in 7 values, but you've only listed 4 variables...?

Comment: I want to ignore the "_" delimiter

Comment: Please show some lines of data.  You've outlined a schema, but not shown any 'real' data.

Comment: Much better: read using `fgets()`, the tokenize!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use `fscanf()` for this, then this format should do it:

```
fscanf(f, "%d_%[^_]_%[^_]_%d", &number, name, name1, &number2);
```

That assumes that the delimiters are single underscores, and it does not accommodate the two strings being empty.  It *does* accommodate leading whitespace before each number (which will be ignored), and the two strings will be permitted to span lines. Both of those potential issues could be addressed, though rejecting whitespace before the numbers would require using `%[` directives instead of %d, and therefore scanning into strings.

Overall, this is probably a lot more trouble than it's worth.  It is very frequently better to write your own parsing function than to rely on the `scanf()` functions for handling any but the simplest of formatting.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as the code currently stands, you have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format,
>   the behavior is undefined.

As we see, in your case,

```
fscanf(f, "%d %[^_]_ %s %[^_]_ %s %[^_]_ %d", &number, name, name1, &number2)
         |=================================|   |=============================|
               7 conversion specifiers                only 4 arguments!!!
                 in the format sting
```

Remember, the `[` and `]` pair actually forms conversion specifiers and they need corresponding argument for the scanned result to be saved.

**Suggestion:**

That said, you may want to use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read the data and [`strtok()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to tokenize the input to get the individual tokens.

Answer (score 2):

What you have currently:

```
fscanf(f, "%d %[^_]_ %s %[^_]_ %s %[^_]_ %d", &number, name, name1, &number2)
```

is matching a number followed by a space, then a series of characters not containing an underscore, then an underscore and a space etc... so totally nothing like what you're actually expecting. Plus, each of those `%...` will expect a corresponding variable to store the value in.

To get what you want you want the following.

```
fscanf(f, "%d_%[^_]_%[^_]_%d", &number, name, name1, &number2);
```

and don't forget to check what value it returns - anything less than 4 means it didn't find all 4 values.